# SMS Broadcastreceiver - Update main activity variable after kicking off

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a sms broadcastreceiver that reads out the text to the user on an incoming sms.  The problem arises when another text is received while the app is reading the first text.  So to prevent multiple sms coming in I want to set a flag in the main activity that states it's reading the text and to cancel the new sms receiver.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

aren you using a text to speech engine? ..if just call tts.stop

here is from the [TTS android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html):

```
stop()
Interrupts the current utterance (whether played or rendered to file) and discards other utterances in the queue.
```

after calling stop proceed to play your new speech.

update: another alternative, just check if the engine is already speaking and if so then dont do anything
.
from the docs:

```
isSpeaking()
Checks whether the TTS engine is busy speaking.
```

update:
You'll need to pass into the intent your raising a data flag to tell the other fresh activity whats going on

so if your calling an explicit intent to launch a class you are probably calling it like this(with your launch flags you mentioned):

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

instead pass in an extra flag with it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("isSpeaking", tts.isSpeaking());
startActivity(intent)
```

then in your launched activity on onCreate just read the data from the intent like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();

Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

boolean flag= extras.getBoolean("isSpeaking");
```

if that doesn't work then just use a static flag in your activity. im not sure if its thread safe so i'll use volatile here as well but something like `static volatile boolean isSpeaking;`

update:  I would remove the flags you have on the launch intent (ie. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)  and then in the activity override onNewIntent() and check for a boolean flag.  Launch the intent the same way i described above sending a boolean extra flag in a bundle.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("isSpeaking",false))
        {
            //do some things  here like ignore speaking or stop TTS etc
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to read the new incoming sms at all if it's already reading an sms aloud.  I have more going on than just reading the sms aloud like allowing a reply and so on. So for that reason I don't want to interrupt the current sms.

Comment: i updated my answer. let me know if it helps you at all.

Comment: I don't think this will work either because like i said it's listening for responses as well as speaking. I can check if it's speaking or maybe if it's listening i suppose. When I launch the activity from the broadcastreceiver i am using intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); This code will always produce a new activity hence not knowing if it's listening or speaking.  So what flags should i use?

Comment: ok first tell me is the broadcast receiver in the same class file as the text to speech stuff ?or does the activity your launching have the text to speech engine stuff instead ?

Comment: The broadcast receiver is separate.

Comment: if my update doesn't work then just use a static flag in your activity. im not sure if its thread safe so i'll use volatile here as well but something like static volatile boolean isSpeaking;

Comment: I see what you're suggesting and I don't think that will work. The problem is that I have a broadcast receiver that is launching my activity on an incoming sms. The flags that I'm using are closing any existing activity and creating a new activity from the receiver. I couldn't find a way to make it work using existing activity, feel free to suggest flags to work this way. So when the new activity opens regardless of what extras I pass in it will always show that nothing is open since it's being recreated. I hope that made sense.

Comment: you could put the static flag inside the broadcastReciever instead if you want to preserve it. But about creating new activities ..i'd just override onNewIntent() and then you can check flags you passed in from the launch intent.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm after. What flags would I use?

Comment: I appreciate all of your answers but I don't think I'm being clear enough. I don't want the broadcast receiver to start launch the activity at all if it's already actively speaking or listening which i have defined in my activity with a boolean 'ReadingText'. So if ReadingText == 1 I don't want the broadcastreceiver to even open MainActivity. So how do I check the status of ReadingText (in MainActivity) from my broadcastreceiver?

Comment: make the boolean static.  so declare it like static boolean ReadingText; in the broadcastreceiver make a reference to it like this MainActivity.ReadingText

Comment: Thanks. I went a different direction with this and am now saving to the preferences the state and updating accordingly.